# Ubuntu 12.10 upgrade is stalled

Tags: upgrade, 12.10, dist-upgrade

My Ubuntu is upgrading to 12.10 at the moment but since 4 hours or more I see only previous packages get restored and nothing happen.

If I exit the upgrading now is all my previous data lost or does the Computer boot my old Ubuntu? I had a problem that is similar to this before while installing Linux on my fathers notebook. After the installation got crashed the Computer wasn't able to boot and I wasn't able to reinstall it.

I need help I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

if you decide to quit upgrade i would recommend to install aptitude `with sudo apt-get install aptitude` and run `sudo apt-get safe-upgrade` or `sudo apt-get update -f` and `sudo apt-get -f install`.Once i upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04 and it took almost 2.5-3 hours.If system is full of files and setting that can be a reason why it took to upgrade for so long

Comment: Oct 22 20:17:01 ubuntu CRON[5176]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly) what does that mean? it's the last message i saw in the installation window

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/402781/what-is-run-parts-in-etc-crontab-and-how-do-i-use-it maybe this will help